# Better way to obtain a smaller vertical line | scaled to math?

Tags: symbols, scaling, scalebox

I am trying to write the following line as can be seen below

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\Huge $\cup \ \cap \ \raisebox{0.30 ex}{\scalebox{1}[0.62]{$\mid$}}$ 
\end{document}
```

Which results in

[image]

Is there an easier or better way to make sure the vertical line `\mid`
is scaled correctly to `\cup` and `\cap`? In particular

- They should have the same *baseline*, *height* and *width*.

My solution feels very hackish and not quite right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Computer Modern, use `pict2e`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{color} % for the comparison

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cbar}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\c@bar\relax}}
\newcommand{\c@bar}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$#1\cup$}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}%
  \mkern1mu
  \raisebox{-\dp\z@}{%
    \begin{picture}(0,1)
    \roundcap
    \c@bar@thickness{#1}%
    \Line(0,0)(0,1.03)
    \end{picture}%
  }%
  \mkern1mu
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\c@bar@thickness}[1]{%
  \linethickness{%
    \ifx#1\displaystyle 1\fontdimen8\textfont\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle 1\fontdimen8\textfont\else
    \ifx#1\scriptstyle 0.85\fontdimen8\scriptfont\else
    0.75\fontdimen8\scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 3
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

${\cup}{\cap}{\cbar}$

$\scriptstyle{\cup}{\cap}{\cbar}$

$\scriptscriptstyle{\cup}{\cap}{\cbar}$

${\cup}\mkern-2.3mu{\textcolor{red}{\cbar}}{\textcolor{red}{\cup}}\mkern-2.3mu{\cbar}$
${\cap}\mkern-2.3mu{\textcolor{red}{\cbar}}{\textcolor{red}{\cap}}\mkern-2.3mu{\cbar}$

$\scriptstyle{\cup}\mkern-2.4mu{\textcolor{red}{\cbar}}{\textcolor{red}{\cup}}\mkern-2.4mu{\cbar}$
$\scriptstyle{\cap}\mkern-2.4mu{\textcolor{red}{\cbar}}{\textcolor{red}{\cap}}\mkern-2.4mu{\cbar}$

$\scriptscriptstyle{\cup}\mkern-2.8mu{\textcolor{red}{\cbar}}{\textcolor{red}{\cup}}\mkern-2.8mu{\cbar}$
$\scriptscriptstyle{\cap}\mkern-2.8mu{\textcolor{red}{\cbar}}{\textcolor{red}{\cap}}\mkern-2.8mu{\cbar}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`\stretchrel` from the `scalerel` package allows you to do such things.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\Huge $\cup \ \cap \ \stretchrel*{\mid}{\cap}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems closer, but still not a perfect match. When I overlay the vertical line and the intersection symbol it looks like this https://i.imgur.com/8bm55vi.png

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I see. I am actually surprised because I always thought `\stretchrel` would provide perfect fits.

Comment: Interestingly the `\cap` and `\cup` claim to have zero depth.